# Drools Stream mode negative patterns

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools

i have a question about stream mode in Drools.
I'm using this rule

```
declare MetaMessage
        @role(event)
end
 
rule 'rule1' ruleflow-group 'default'  
    when  
        $inMess : MetaMessage() from entry-point 'default'
        not(MetaMessage(this != $inMess, this after [0s,10s] $inMess) from entry-point 'default')
    then  
        //do things
end
```

If i send a MetaMessage, i expect the rule to execute after the 10s specified, but nothing appens.
If i send a new MetaMessage, after 10 seconds, the rule executes.

**Edit**: if i change the rule and take away the not, it works like a charm

I'm not sure what am i doing wrong.

This is how i create the KieBase

```java
KieBaseConfiguration config = KieServices.Factory.get().newKieBaseConfiguration();
config.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);
KieBase kieBase = kieHelper.build(config);
KieSession kieSession = kieBase.newKieSession();
```

**Edit 2**
I fire the rules using `fireAllRules()` everytime a new MetaMessage is inserted in a Kafka queue.
So i have a consumer collecting messages and inserting them in the session like this

```java
EntryPoint ep = kieSession.getEntryPoint("default");
ep.insert(metaMessage);
kieSession.fireAllRules();
```

**Edit 3**
I have another simple rule that gets executed toghether with the previous one

```
rule "AccumulatedTest"

    when
        accumulate(MetaMessage( timestamp > 0 ); $cnt: count(1))
    then
        log.info("Message n: "+$cnt);
end
```

The first time a message gets inserted (when the kieSession is newly created) i get the info "Message n: 0".
But then this rule does not fire anymore.

If any other message gets inserted in the session the rule does not fire

Comment: How are you doing the rules? fireAllRules() or fireUntilHalt()?

Comment: @EstebanAliverti I'm using fireAllRules()

Comment: just one time? Or do you have some kind of scheduled job that periodically executes `fireAllRules()`?

Comment: I use `fireAllRules()` everytime there is a new `MetaMessage` using java

Comment: I edited the question with some more details about the ```fireAllRules()``` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @EstebanAliverti and @Mike, i have fixed the problem.

Let me elaborate:

- I had to create a scheduled `fireAllRules()` that runs every 1s (as @EstebanAliverti suggested)
- I removed the `ruleflow-group` from the rule because (as @Mike suggested) the focus switches back to the default agenda group and, in my implementation, i cannot pass the agenda group from the scheduled execution

So now the `fireAllRules()` runs every 1s and there is no ruleflow or agenda group

Now the rule looks like this and it works as intended

```
declare MetaMessage
        @role(event)
end
 
rule 'rule1'
    when  
        $inMess : MetaMessage() 
        not(MetaMessage(this != $inMess, this after [0s,10s] $inMess) )
    then  
        //do things
end
```

Last but not least, since i removed the entrypoint as i wasn't using the funcionality, i now insert the messages directly inside the KieSession

```java
kieSession.insert(metaMessage);
kieSession.fireAllRules();
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `ruleflow-group 'default'`, thus you must set focus to agenda group to get rule executed, like `getSession().getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("default").setFocus();`

Most likely you set focus before or after event insertion. After inserting first message you set focus but no rule was added to the agenda (rule is not yet eligible for execution) at that time, and focus get reset to main agenda group. After 10 seconds you state that no rule was triggered despite that rule was added to 'default' agenda (because main group has focus). You insert second message and set focus to 'default' agenda which executes the rule from the agenda being triggered by the first message.

Rule is getting executed if you

1. remove `ruleflow-group` (latest documentation promote `agenda-group`)
2. add `auto-focus true` to the rule
3. set agenda group focus after 10 seconds

See [how agenda group works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870192/understanding-agenda-group-in-drools)

Comment: Given that he mentioned that by modifying the condition of the rule the rule fired, I guess the problem is not related to the `ruleflow-group` of the rule. But in case the `ruleflow-group` is the problem, you gave a great explanation!

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed response, but i'm on vacation.
I tried removing the `ruleflow-group` from the rule, and obvioulsy from the code, but it did not work.
I have to test a few more things but it might take a while.
In any case, thanks fro the suggestion, i'll let you know if i can make this work